# Angular 2 can't do actions in subscribe method after service called

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service to authenticate my user but I don't know what to do with the  data that I received. I wan't to redirect the user to the correct page depending of his role and display his name in the page.
I tried different things but when I called the router or a function it's never find. It look's like it's not in the same context. How can I do that ?

Here is my login component :

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {User} from "../models/user";
    import {AuthenticationService} from "../services/authentication.service";
    import {Router} from "@angular/router";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
      providers: [AuthenticationService]
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      user:User = new User();
      result: any;

      constructor(private authenticationService:AuthenticationService,
private router:Router) {
      }

      loginAction(){
        this.authenticationService.login(this.user)
            .subscribe(function(result){
              this.result = result;
              console.log(this.result); // result : {token: "ABCDE....", "email":"test@test.com", "username": "Jack James", role:"ADMIN"}
              this.doSth();     //Never called I supposed it's not the same context 
               this.router.navigate(['home']); // router is not find
              // I wan't to do actions to redirect to another page and display the user currently logged in
            },
              err => {
                // Log errors if any
                console.log(err);
            });
      }

      doSth(){
        console.log("Do something");
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Comment: What does 'router is not find' means? router undefined? router can't find the route?

Comment: It's ok you can see the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is following line: `.subscribe(function(result){` !!

With that `function()`-syntax the `this`-scope is lost!

You have to use the arrow-syntax `() =>` ..

Like this: `.subscribe((result) => {`.

That's it, now you can use `this.router....` :)